# Can I convert only time into timestamp?

Tags: android, timestamp

I'm trying to measure time while a user plays a game and I have to store that playing time to database. (I will use it later to make a rank.)

I've heard that I'd better use timestamp if the data I want to store is about time.

But after I searched, I could only see the examples that converting 'date'&time to timestamp. 
I only need to store playing time without date, so I'm wondering if it's possible.

If it is, please give me some examples too. 
Thank you.

Comment: What you have heard is sage advice.  Consider the case where a player starts playing at 11pm one day, and finishes 3am the next day.  Using only time alone, it might be ambiguous how to interpret this data.  But, using date + time, it is clear how you should calculate things.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thank you for your opinion! I thought I don't have to get date again because I'm actually saving records using date in my database. Maybe I have to consider to rethink my database structure... Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a commenter said, I strongly recommend using date & time. However, if you really want / need to just use time:

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    long timestamp = cal.getTimeInMillis() - System.currentTimeMillis();
```

This creates a calendar, sets it to last midnight, and get the number of milliseconds since then.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It's really useful!

Comment: @WonGyeong No worries! Make sure to mark your question as solved (tick next to an answer) if it has been!